# Using JAVA, how can I parse .cshtml file and add parameters for the existing C# code in that file

Tags: java, razor, jsoup, html-parser

I have some .CSHTML files that were incorrectly generated by a tool. I would like to modify the C# code in them to append additional parameters and remove incorrect parameters from method calls.

I've used [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML and JSP files. I am able to add or remove attribute in the HTML and JSP files via JSoup DOM iteration.

But in the .CSHTML files contains C# code (I'm new to C#) and couldn't get control over the code. Hence **I am not able to append parameters for that C# code using JSoup library**. For example,

```
<td>
    @Html.Label(Resource.Get("Label_Name"), new Dictionary<string,object>{{ "Class","label"},{ "name","Name"},{ "id","Name"}}) 
</td>
<td>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.TextBox1,new Dictionary<string,object>{{ "Class","txtfield controlWidth"},{ "name","TextBox1"},{ "id","TextBox1"}})
</td>
```

As above "@Html.xxxx" codes are treated as value for the 'tr' tag in Jsoup DOM iteration. I could only think on adding if..else logic to add or remove parameters as snippet given below. I **don't know what is the standard way of parsing such .cshtml file**.

```
if(str.contains("@Html.")) {
  ctrlType=str.substring(str.indexOf('.')+1,str.indexOf('('));
  if(ctrlType.equalsIgnorecase("Label")) {
   // logic to add parameters.
  }
}
```

**Using Java**, is there **way to parse the .cshtml file and add or remove parameters for C# code** ? Can you please suggest to solve the problem with open standard API?

Comment: Are you asking for the logic to parse the Razor syntax, or are you asking for a way to actually parse, modify and regenerate the C# code? I'd be surprised if there was that in Java. What exactly are you trying to do to the .cshtml files?

Comment: Using Java technology, I want to parse the .cshtml file and iterate the C# code (that starts @Html -  as it has some parameters left out / added extra while generating the code via some tool). Now, I would like to appened the additional parameters or remove the unwanted parameters while iterating. For that, any standard or open API available to parse .cshtml file in Java and to manipulate over the C# code.

Comment: That's useful context. Old jokes aside, I think your best bet would be to use regular expressions to match and modify the text rather than try and understand the C# code in Java.